# How to make org "tour"?

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

Can anyone give guidance on how to implement something like http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/ in a salesforce org?
WalkMe is not an option, but trying to achieve something similar. To make my question more specific, how do I make my own custom tour to help new end users navigate a salesforce org for the first time? For example, when they click on a tab (like Accounts), a popup would occur that can guide them through or at least display text that can explain how to use Accounts).

Comment: Are you looking for such solution inside your visualforce page, if yes what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @Himanshu I have not started a VF page yet. Just wondering what the best approach is. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: A chrome (or your browser of choice) extension might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement intro to your org there are below points to consider:

- You can not implement this on standard Objects tab like account because to implement this, you need to insert this script and html markup.
- If you want to implement this to your visualforce page then you can achieve this easily by given documentation which seems easy.
- If you still want to implement this on standard page, then you can achieve this only on record page using execute script by button click, like `start intro`

Let me know if you need more help regarding this :) .